# Objects in canvas get exponentially faster when I use the setInterval function

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, setinterval

When I use the setInterval() to control the game loop. It responds by making the stars get faster and faster. At each turn of the loop the velocity is getting greater. How can I keep the velocity constant?

```
function Star(x, y, rad, velocity, fill){
    this.x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 999);//this create a random number between 0 and 599 on the x axis
    this.y = 0;
    this.rad = Math.floor((Math.random() * 30) + 15);//this create a random number between 10 and 30 for the radius
    this.velocity = 5;
    this.fill = fill 

    this.draw = function(){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;             
    ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.rad, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    this.y += this.velocity;
    }
}

function createMultipleStars(){
    for (var i = 0; i <= numOfStars; i++)
    stars[i] = new Star(i * 50, 10, i, i, "rgba(255,215,0,0.6)");
}


function step() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i<= numOfStars; i++)
    stars[i].draw();
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
   //spaceShip.drawSpaceShip();
var myVar2 = setInterval(function(){ createMultipleStars() }, 4000);
var myVar = setInterval(function(){ step() }, 4000);
```

Comment: Don't use `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame` simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Your `step` function calls itself asynchronously through `requestAnimationFrame`.

Then, each time you call `step`, the result is something like this:

```
step ──> step ──> step ──> step ──> …
```

However, you call `step` in a `setInterval`. Therefore, a new call of `step` will be done periodically:

```
setInterval ──> step ──> step ──> step ──> step ──> …
     ├─────────────────> step ──> step ──> step ──> …
     ├──────────────────────────> step ──> step ──> …
     ├───────────────────────────────────> step ──> …
     ⋮
```

Therefore, don't use `setInterval(step)`. Replace it with `step()`.

Or alternatively, don't make `step` call itself.

Comment: I want to time the game, so I can make it faster as the game continues. I need both the interval loop and requestAnimationFrame loop. Is there a way of resetting the velocity variable after each time the loop iterates. @Oriol

Answer (score 0):

`reqestAnimationFrame` works like `setTimeout` except you don't tell it when to execute, it tells you when you should execute.

So in effect the loop:

```
function step () {
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
```

is similar to:

```
setInterval(step);
```

So in effect, you're creating more and more animation loops each interval, not executing `step` each interval. The `step` function will execute itself in its own `requestAnimationFrame` loop.